Unity new build do not update
I have a project with procedural terrain generation, grass generation, working well.
I make a build for my android device, everything is working.
It has low fps, so I dedice to not generate grass to see the difference. I comment the section that generate grass in my script, so it do not generate grass anymore. Works fine in editor + game window (playmode).
Each time I make a new build for my device, it is completed ("succeeded") BUT grass is still there.
I am becoming crazy, I just want that it FORGET the previous version of my app and build the new one that works like in the playmode of my project.
I have this warning :
Unable to find player assembly: Library/PlayerScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler/BurstAOTSettings,UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly[]) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:498)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor:DoGenerate (UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly[]) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:265)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:189)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)


Unity 2021.3.21f1
I tried:

change package name and version
refresh script
reimport script
changing name of the script and so his calls in other script
reimport all
clean build
deleting build folder and uninstall* previous apk on my device
reopen unity


sounds like I'd be mad if i were you, it sounds like you did a lot of sensible things to clear out any left overs..  Im assuming you killed processes and uninstalled the apk not just deleted it from your android device?

I uninstalled app form the android device, long press and choose "uninstall". I don't understand where the problem is…

Wdym by killing processes? In the editor or android device? I will try to restart both my pc and the android device and retry. It should kill any processes

Try deleting the Library & Temp folders in your project.

killing the process on the android device.. in case it still thinks its running

Thank you guys, it was indeed a process that was wessing up. Restarting both pc and device worked. Jay I will try your solution, maybe it is faster than restarting devices

you can reply if you want BugFinder and i'll taq it as answer

It sounds like its not seeing the update on the android device. Id kill processes and then uninstall.
Ps. As you found a restart obviously does kinda the same but it did sound like the android device at fault as windows cant use apk so would be unlikely to keep it in use and not say so. Its usually vocal on these things.
